# What is the advantage to explicitly connecting to a Mongo Replica Set?

Tags: mongodb

Obviously, I know why to use a replica set in general.

But, I'm confused about the difference between connecting directly to the PRIMARY mongo instance and connecting to the replica set. Specifically, if I am connecting to Mongo from my node.js app using Mongoose, is there a compelling reason to use connectSet() instead of connect()? I would assume that the failover benefits would still be present with connect(), but perhaps this is where I am wrong...

The reason I ask is that, in mongoose, the connectSet() method seems to be less documented and  well-used. Yet, I cannot imagine a scenario where you would NOT want to connect to the set, since it is recommended to always run Mongo on a 3x+ replica set...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you connect only to the primary then you get failover (that is, if the primary fails, there will be a brief pause until a new master is elected).  Replication within the replica set also makes backups easier.  A downside is that all writes and reads go to the single primary (a MongoDB replica set only has one primary at a time), so it can be a bottleneck.

Allowing connections to slaves, on the other hand, allows you to scale for reads (not for writes - those still have to go the primary).  Your throughput is no longer limited by the spec of the machine running the primary node but can be spread around the slaves.  However, you now have a new problem of stale reads; that is, there is a chance that you will read stale data from a slave.

Now think hard about how your application behaves.  Is it read-heavy? How much does it need to scale?  Can it cope with stale data in some circumstances?

Incidentally, the point of a minimum 3 members in the replica set is to offer resiliency and safe replication, *not* to provide multiple nodes to connect to.  If you have 3 nodes and you lose one, you still have enough nodes to elect a new primary *and* have replication to a backup node.

Comment: "Allowing connections to slaves" -- is this accomplished by the very act of doing a connectSet()? I take it rs.slaveOk(true); must also be executed? Is there any way to control this, eg. create a rule like this "finds on collection X should be run on SECONDARY servers unless the find fails, in which case, revert to PRIMARY?" This is more of an intellectual curiosity point for me... I'm aware that, really, all the I/O should go to the PRIMARY. I'm just curious if I could use this to squeeze performance in a pinch.

Comment: slaveOK is deprecated now; use readPreference.  You can set a default readPreference for each connection but override it on a per-collection or per-operation basis (and the same applies to write concerns).  With 2.2, you can combine the basic readPreference options with tagging (arbitrary subsets of the replica set) in quite subtle ways